# Minification brings static variables to left side of comparison

Tags: javascript

I just noticed something interesting on most minification libraries.

This is a method from angular.js

```
function isNumber(value) {return typeof value === 'number';}
```

As you can see `typeof value` value is on the left side of the comparison on the source code. But after minification it looks like this.

```
function Q(a){return"number"===typeof a}
```

Now the static member is at the left side of the comparison on angular.min.js minified code.

All cases of `evaluated value === static` comparisons are converted to `static === evaluated value`.

I just want to learn the reason of it. Is it better for reliability or performance or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just shorter. If they left it in the original order, it would need a space after `return`:

```
function Q(a){return typeof a==="number"}
```

But the quote around `number` is a token delimiter, so no space is needed. The above line is one character longer than the minified version.

Answer (score 1):

Because javascript engine allows return statement to be followed by string without a space. And that simply... saves space.